How to Add DisplayName when deploying Azure DevOps Pipelines with yaml
I'm trying to add displayName to my yaml code when deploying pipelines, however when I run the pipeline the displayName doesn't appear.
I am expecting the displayName 'PreDeployment' to appear:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    displayName: PreDeployment
    azureSubscription: 'NewConnectionName'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/PrePostDeploymentScript.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

I just get the displayname 'AzurePowerShell'

Any thoughts?

The 'displayName' is a 'common' property and must be used like below:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: PreDeployment
  inputs:    
    azureSubscription: 'NewConnectionName'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/PrePostDeploymentScript.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/caplogic-warehouse-dev-df/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroup) -DataFactoryName $(DataFactory) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

You may refer this MS doc for more info: steps.task definition
